# Passing column values from a table into WHERE clause

Tags: sql

My apologies if this has already been solved, but I have been searching for a solution for a couple of days and nothing seems to work in my situation.

I am trying to pass some values from a staging table (Table_A) that I created into a WHERE clause in my query.

I joined to the staging table in my query and my WHERE clause looks like this :
WHERE B.ID IN (Select ID from Table_A)

The query takes about 45 minutes to run with the above WHERE statement, whereas it takes 6 minutes for it to run without joining to the staging table (Table A) and passing the values manually in the WHERE clause like below :

WHERE B.ID IN (Value 1, Value 2, Value 3.. etc)

I am not exactly sure what is causing the query to run much slower. I am trying to use the modified query (with the Select statement in it) in a package, which is why I need to pass the values without having to enter it manually. Does anyone have any idea how I could solve this? Can this be done in SSIS instead? Thank you

Comment: You either join or use exists/in, not both at the same time. If exists is slow, then you may have some index missing.

Answer (score 0):

You want to start with the query plan and see what's going on.  Second rebuild your statistics when the table is populated to make sure the optimiser's assumptions are correct.  If there is an index and it thinks there's only a few rows but there are in fact millions then that can cause the behavior you are seeing.

If it's not already, you can try indexing TABLE_A.ID and B.ID but as a staging table you might not want that.  If that's the case then try staging TABLE_A.ID into its own table and using that (cluster the index on ID).  It may be that the row size is so big that the scan etc. just takes that much I/O.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the staging table may be populated with just 50 or so rows in just one column, so it is a very small table.

Comment: Did you rebuild the statistics?

Answer (score 0):

`IN` is often poorly optimized.  I find that `EXISTS` often works better:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table_A A
              WHERE B.ID = A.ID
             )
```

In particular, this can make use of an index on `Table_A(ID)` -- which is automatically there if `ID` is the primary key.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately the query still takes 30 to 45 minutes to run.